# Ember Inspector addon not showing data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am creating an app using Ember.js. I downloaded the Inspector for Firefox and Chrome and most of it seems to work fine, however, if I go to the data tab of the inspector, I just have a blank screen with no access to any of the data loaded.

I am using the DS.RESTAdapter and my application is pulling the data correctly and displaying it, it just doesn't show up in the add-on. Am I missing something? I would show some code examples but I am not even sure what to show.

Comment: Version numbers of all the things?

Comment: Ember Inspector 1.3.1
Ember 1.6.1
Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.5
Handlebars 1.1.2
jQuery 1.11.0